Google Analytics: insert from unknown-package names
We use firebase for our android apps and on 19th October started seeing lot of crashlytics errors for unknown apps. This errors where not visible on google play store console. After discussing with firebase support team it was informed that its a issue with reverse engineering of apk and it was resolved by firebase team via backend. Here is the error the for same. java.lang.RuntimeException:Unable to get provider com.rachittechnology.TheCriminalLawAct2013.NXcX7M: java.lang.NullPointerException: key can't be null
Now crashlytics error is resolved, however we have started seeing lot of inserts into bigquery from unknown packages. We have implemented SHA certificate on firebase console as well as within GCP API for the app.
What you expected to happen: Unknown packages data should not be allowed in bigquery
Steps to reproduce:
NA - below list of packages are seen daily in bigquery database.

com.appgame7.friutslegend com.community.oneroom
com.de.modern.bus.driving.car.parking.game.challenge
com.draw.to.pee.bo com.game.foldpuzzle com.gamovation.chessclubpilot
com.gun.lightsaber.scifigunsounds com.haftnR8T4ZgRoLEi
com.hungrystudio.blockblast.amazon com.hZVoqbRXhUWsP51a
com.idle.egg.factory.inc.tycoon
com.ironmeta.security.turbo.proxy.vpntomato.pro
com.iwaredesigns.prodarts
com.live.earthview.maps.gpsfinder.globalsatellite.apps
com.lw.hitechcircuit.launcher com.mellat.music.videomaker
com.mgc.RopeHero.ViceTown com.millgame.alignit com.mobirix.driveking
com.musicplayer.music com.myyearbook.m
com.officedocument.word.docx.document.viewer
com.playmous.hotel.master4amazon com.playspare.shapeshifting
com.pQUZJMiXkp105xkC com.pt.wshhp
com.soulcompany.bubbleshooter.relaxing com.syjfyn.neszc.dwrsdaek.nbgif
com.tangramgames.gourddoll.wordcrush
com.tripledot.triple.tile.match.pair.game.three.master.object
com.ushareit.listenit com.yogaworkout.flexrun3d com.zeynab.weather
com.zombiewar.thelastsurvivor dev.mgtc.artheistpuzzle hausa.radiobbc
linkdesks.tile.match.fun net.fnvdr.fdqdxd net.nlzjn.cltbdo.vvszsksm
net.urxbzdcx.wemx.ntjbbb.zdwdds org.cngjj.rpbzo.stfm
org.dsmxle.auhp.fqf org.kdapdr.pjkvfwd.uebky.xizbyw
org.ndq.gzyy.ydepnv org.qpgqeq.gqim.huzrwe.lfphu
org.tahvobg.sels.fbbdgu.bkakmu org.vuf.exlxxlr
org.znrsmsa.cvqtlljo.jbggcnd.rsx pdf.reader.pdfviewer.pdfeditor
photo.editor.photoeditor.photoeditorpro puzzle.blockpuzzle.cube.relax
puzzle.game.find.differences
translate.all.language.translator.cameratranslator
water.color.sort.puzzle.games
xhub.freevpn.vpnproxy.vpnfree.fastvpn.proxy.vpn

Reached out to firebase support team and was informed to contact analytics support. Verified SHA signatures on firebase and in google play console. Both are correctly setup for android apps.
Opened a bug https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/379591514?pli=1
Question:
Q1. How this packages are inserting data into bigquery? Find root cause? ( have access to bigquery and analytics)
Q2.How to stop them?
